# What's the difference between the Click event and a user defined event in C#

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to understand events better, and i've seen some lines of code that made me confused..
I know that, for example, when I want to declare an event and later subscribe to it i will do like this:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
...
MyEvent += MyFunction;
MyEvent += new SomeClass().SomeFunction;
```

So here I declared the event and subscrbed some functions to it. It's easy.

Later I found this piece of code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i =0; i<5; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Button " + i.ToString();
        Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.BtnFunction);
    }
}

void BtnFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    Label1.Text = btn.Text;
}
```

Now what I can't understand is this line here: `btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.BtnFunction);`
The questions are:

- Why do I use the `new EventHandler(this.BtnFuncion)`? Isn't the `Click` event of a type `EventHandler`?
- Does `EventHandler` have a constructor and why does it takes now the function that should subscribe to this event?

Comment: edit: I forgot to write about covariance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net BCL's event and User defined event are not different. `Click` Event is like the following:

```
public event EventHandler Click;
```

[EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler) is a delegate type, which is used in .Net BCL's event. I think you have seen some event handlers, like `void function(object sender, EventArgs e)`. `EventHandler` is like the follwing:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

The second delegate, `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` is used when event required to send some information. For example:

```
public event EventHandler<SomeClass> MyEvent;
```

edit: Notice that `SomeClass` is recommended to inherit `EventArgs` for covariance

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense! Because EventHandler is a delegate it makes us use the (object sender, EventArgs e). This made this sink into my mind! Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

This is the short notation of assign an Event Handler:

```
MyEvent += MyFunction;
```

And this is the long notation:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.BtnFunction);
```

This line can be written like this:

```
btn.Click += this.BtnFunction;
```

Comment: Oh, now i get it :) Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.  This is called [syntax sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_sugar).  You don't *have* to help because the compiler can figure out that you meant to use a delegate.  This sugar is important because without it you would have to write this to unsubscribe the event:

```
    btn.Click -= new EventHandler(this.BtnFunction);
```

Which sets off major alarm bells to an unsuspecting new C# programmer that's learning the language: "Create a *new* delegate to *remove* an event handler??"  Yes.  Really.   Nobody blows a fuse over:

```
    btn.Click -= this.BtnFunction;
```

Even the delegate constructor call is syntax sugar, it actually requires *two* arguments under the hood.  One that sets the Target property and another that sets the Method.  The target is inferred by the compiler, it is *this*.  The two argument constructor syntax is not legal in C#, a language like C++/CLI has it.

Comment: Thank You for your answer Hans. This clears the questions i have about Events.